# Create new web application button is disabled

Tags: sharepoint-server

I install sharepoint server 2016, and when i try to create a new web application, the button is disabled, i add role for my system account but it is same, i use Chrome

[image: user role]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found a sollution, it's stupid but work, i change internet option of IE to local internet and i change setting like image, finally i run IE as admin

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to start the Central Administration site on the server using the link created during the installation
Start> (type "Central Admin").
It should run the default browser "as administrator".

Comment: I do it, but the same